# CentOS + Rails + nginx + Unicorn + MySQL + RVM(?) howto?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

Can someone point me to a very good recent guide on how to setup CentOS  + Rails + nginx + Unicorn + MySQL + RVM(?) ?

Or could provide some instructions here?

I'm also not sure if to use RVM on production server, Will that be a good idea?

Comment: This is a very specific specification. Have you tried installing each part individually? Regarding RVM: Are you planning to switch Ruby versions on the production server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RVM, Ruby and Rails is fairly straightforward to setup in CentOS.

Install requirements:

```
sudo yum install git patch pcre pcre-devel openssl openssl-devel curl curl-devel libxslt-devel libxml2-devel sqlite-devel nginx
```

Install RVM:

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

Reload your profile:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Run rvm requirements and install any of the listed dependencies:

```
rvm requirements
```

Update rvm (just in case):

```
rvm get head && rvm reload
```

Install the latest version of Ruby:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Setup your RVM environment:

```
rvm use 1.9.3@projectname --create --default
```

Update gems to the latest version:

```
gem update --system
```

Install Rails:

```
gem install rails
```

Install unicorn:

```
gem install unicorn
```

You should check out the [defunkt github repo](https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn). There are a lot of great configuration files in there for Unicorn and Nginx that work well.

Once you create your rails project, read the comments in the unicorn.rb and nginx files in the defunkt project to configure them correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I have started a new example project to show very similar setup:

- nginx proxy
- unicorn server
- sqlite3
- rvm (head version)
- ruby-1.9.3-p125
- bundler
- rails 3.2
- capistrano

https://github.com/mpapis/ad

You find there working application with deployment and example nginx config file.

As to the sqlite3 instead of mysql - it's good solution for starting application, you can always switch to bigger database engine when it get's to slow.